# Regex for measuraments unit on both sides of the value (200 g/g 200)

Tags: regex, units-of-measurement

I'm trying to write a regex to capture any measurement unit in a string, considering that the unit can be before or after the number.

What I came up for the moment are two regex.

`/\d*\.?,?\d+\s?(kg|g|l)/gi` that matches with

```
ABC 200g
EFG 5,4 Kg
HIL 2x20l
```

And `(kg|g|l)\s?\d+,?\.?d*` that matches with:

```
ABC g200
EFG kg 5,4
HIL l 20x2
```

How can I join the two regex to match with both:

```
ABC g200
EFG 5,4 Kg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a case insensitive pattern, match an optional `k` and `g` or `l` and an alternation `|` to match the pattern the other way as well.

The optional dot and comma can be in a character class `[.,]?` or else `.?,?` can also match both like `.,`

The word boundaries `\b` prevent a partial match after the unit.

```
\d*[.,]?\d+\s*(?:k?g|l)\b|\b(?:k?g|l)\s*\d*[.,]?\d+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5TU8La/1)

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following regex.

```
(?:(?:(?:\d+)g|(?:g\d+))|(?:(?:l\s*\d+)|(?:\d+\s*l))|(?:(?:\d+,\d+\s*Kg)|(?:kg\s*\d+,\d+)))
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/hnTG8Z/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
(?:                                     ##Starting 1st capturing group from here.
  (?:                                   ##Starting 2nd capturing group from here.
     (?:\d+)g|(?:g\d+)                  ##Matching either digits followed by g OR g followed by digits(both conditions in non-capturing groups here).
  )                                     ##Closing 2nd capturing group here.
  |                                     ##Putting OR condition here.
  (?:                                   ##Starting 3rd capturing group here.
     (?:l\s*\d+)|(?:\d+\s*l)            ##Matching eiter l followed by 0 or more spaces followed by digits OR digits followed by 0 or more spaces followed by l.
  )                                     ##Closing 3rd capturing group here.
  |                                     ##Putting OR condition here.
  (?:                                   ##Starting 4th capturing group here.
     (?:\d+,\d+\s*Kg)|(?:kg\s*\d+,\d+)  ##Checking either digits followed by comma digits spaces Kg OR kg spaces digits comma digits here.
  )                                     ##Closing 4th capturing group here.
)                                       ##Closing 1st capturing group here.
```